# Blender proton bouncing off of "spongey" atom

Tags: collision

Here is my Blender screen shot. I need the proton on the right to bounce off the atom on the left. I need the atom to give a bit (sort of pillow like) when the proton hits it but then regain it's shape when the proton bounces off of it.

Thank you
Dean[image]

Comment: Lattice modifier with an animated strength value is one easy solution.

Comment: Thanks Allen. I appreciate your help. If I could get a few more specifics from you that would help. I am assuming that the lattice modifier goes on the atom? Any other guidance would be appreciated. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Create a lattice object and place it around your molecule with the usual move, rotate, & scale controls.

[image]

The lattice has some controls for resolution.  I'll use 3, but change it to whatever you find works best.

[image]

Add a *Lattice Modifier* to your molecule and use the eyedropper tool to select the lattice.

[image]

Now, select the lattice object and tab into *Edit Mode*.  Moving the individual vertices of the lattice will now have a weighted effect on the molecule mesh.

[image]

You can leave the lattice in its deformed state, and keyframe the strength setting on the *Lattice Modifier* to coincide with the collision from the proton.

Comment: Thanks Allen, this is great! I appreciate you taking the time to provide the screen shots and descriptions.